# How to show buildings from selected area in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, area, building

I am a beginner in mapbox, so please be understanding :)

I'm trying to show 3D buildings only from the selected area (in red area). Unfortunately, I did not find any answer in the documentation or on the Internet, so I decided to ask here if there is such a possibility?
I was thinking about copying Tilesets and somehow extracting buildings but I do not know how.

Do you have any ideas?

Link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/Mativve/pen/RzORMo

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = '--MY-TOKEN--';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mativve/cjxzva0f6042a1cm7710cofya',
  center: [21.005950, 52.231034],
  zoom: 15,
  bearing: 20.80,
  pitch: 53.50
});
```

Comment: Probably need to create an interpolation filter for that layer

Comment: Hmm ok, but how can i do it in mapbox? Or maybe do it in JS?

Comment: Using `setFilter()` on the layer and figuring out the interpolation needed

Comment: Ok I'll try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct support for area-based filtering, but you could achieve something similar (with some caveats), as follows:

1. Call `map.queryRenderedFeatures()` to get all buildings in the current view port.
2. Use Turf's [booleanContains](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanContains) function to create an array of buildings that are within the designated polygon.
3. Construct a filter that matches only those filters, using some other property, such as a building identifier.
4. Call `map.setFilter()` on the buildings layer so that only those buildings are visible.